# Send-MailMessage alternatives for Windows Powershell 7

Tags: powershell

We have a few powershell scripts that are running on a server which use the Send-MailMessage command.

Generally , We have been using Windows Powershell 7 version for my scripts via Task Scheduler.

But when attempting to run my scripts then I got the following the warning message.

My question is : What's alternatives for Send-MailMessage command ?  AFAIK, there is one called Mailozaurr module.

```
WARNING: The command 'Send-MailMessage' is obsolete. This cmdlet does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers. While there is no immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not use Send-MailMessage at this time. See https://aka.ms/SendMailMessage for more information.
```

### Update

```
function SendMail {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false, SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium')]param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateScript({
            $IsMailServerReachable = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $_ -Port 25
            return $IsMailServerReachable.TcpTestSucceeded
        })][string]$MailServer,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][MailAddress]$From,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][MailAddress[]]$To,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][MailAddress[]]$Cc,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Subject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Body, # HTML body
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$FromDisplayName,
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string[]]$Attachments # path to file
    )
    $Mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $Mail.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $Mail.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
    if ($FromDisplayName) {
        $Mail.From = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $From, $FromDisplayName
    } else {
        $Mail.From = $From
    }
    $To | ForEach-Object {$Mail.To.Add($_)}
    $Cc | ForEach-Object {$Mail.Cc.Add($_)}
    if ($Attachments) {$Attachments | ForEach-Object {$Mail.Attachments.Add($_)}}
    $Mail.Subject = $Subject
    $Mail.Body = $Body
    
    $Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($MailServer)
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(('Sending mail ' + ($Mail.Subject | Join-String -DoubleQuote) + ' to ' + ($Mail.To.Address | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',') + ($Mail.Cc.Address | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',') + ' with ' + $Mail.Attachments.Count + ' attachment(s) ' + ($Mail.Attachments.Name | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',')), $To, 'Send')) {
        $Smtp.Send($Mail)
    }
    $Mail.Dispose()
    $Smtp.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: There are no built-in alternatives for this cmdlet. Mailozaurr is one of the modules that attempt to solve this problem. If you're using azure you can look into the [sendMail Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or the powershell cmdlet that wraps this.

Comment: One modern alternative is the third-party [`Send-MailKitMessage`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage) cmdlet, which builds on the third-party [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library.

Comment: See the platform note where the documentation of send-mailmessage links to: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md the problem with send-mailmessage is the smtpclient class. Using the class directly doesn't "solve" the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it until it no longer works. Classic Microsoft, deprecating stuff without actually providing an alternative that works. See M365 Powershell Modules, see new Exchange Admin Center which was missing critical functions for years.

As an alternative, you can use the NET class directly. I have been using this function in Powershell 7, as it allows me to do more stuff (like Sender Display Name, attachments) that is not possible with the built-in cmdlet.

```
function SendMail {
    [CmdletBinding(
        PositionalBinding=$false,
        SupportsShouldProcess=$true,
        ConfirmImpact='Medium'
    )]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [MailAddress]$From,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$FromDisplayName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [MailAddress[]]$To,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [MailAddress[]]$Cc,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [MailAddress[]]$Bcc,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Subject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Body,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$Attachments,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$MailServer,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$Port = 25,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool]$UseSsl = $true
     )

    if (($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('To') -eq $false) -and ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Cc') -eq $false) -and ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Bcc') -eq $false)) {
        throw '$To, $Cc, $Bcc are all empty, aborting'
    }

    # mail object
    $Mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

    if ($FromDisplayName) {
        $Mail.From = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $From, $FromDisplayName
    } else {
        $Mail.From = $From
    }

    # used in a friendly logfile message that shows all recipients
    $RecipientString = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()

    foreach ($_ in $To) {
        $Mail.To.Add($_)
        $RecipientString.Add($_.Address + '(To)')
    }

    foreach ($_ in $Cc) {
        $Mail.CC.Add($_)
        $RecipientString.Add($_.Address + '(Cc)')
    }

    foreach ($_ in $Bcc) {
        $Mail.Bcc.Add($_)
        $RecipientString.Add($_.Address + '(Bcc)')
    }

    $Mail.Subject = $Subject
    $Mail.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $Mail.Body = $Body

    foreach ($_ in $Attachments) {
        $Mail.Attachments.Add($_)
    }

    # mail server object
    $Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    $Smtp.Host = $MailServer
    $Smtp.Port = $Port

    if ($UseSsl -eq $true) {
        $Smtp.EnableSsl = $true
    }

    # friendly logfile message that shows all recipients
     $ConfirmationString = "Sending mail $($Mail.Subject | Join-String -DoubleQuote) to $($RecipientString | Join-String -Separator ',') with $($Mail.Attachments.Count) attachment(s) $($Mail.Attachments.Name | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',')"
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ConfirmationString, $To, 'Send')) {
        $Smtp.Send($Mail)
    }
    $Mail.Dispose()
    $Smtp.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  btw I want to add Cc and Bcc and Priority attributes. How can we do that?

Comment: Use the $Mail.CC and $Mail.BCC properties of the MailMessage class

Comment: I have updated my script. `if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(('Sending mail ' + ($Mail.Subject | Join-String -DoubleQuote) + ' to ' + ($Mail.To.Address | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',') + ($Mail.Cc.Address | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',') + ' with ' + $Mail.Attachments.Count + ' attachment(s) ' + ($Mail.Attachments.Name | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ',')), $To, 'Send')) {
        $Smtp.Send($Mail)`

Comment: Added To and High Priority properties. Am I Correct?

Comment: The reason why Send-MailMessage is deemed insecure is because of system.net.smtpclient. Using this class directly doesn't actually "solve" the problem and actually makes the code more complex. See https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md : this is the document send-mailmessage links to

Comment: @Arbelac I have updated the function, added Cc, Bcc, Port and SSL capability