# Email sending with attachment

Tags: powershell

I tried this code but I'm getting an exception calling 'send' with "1" argument(s): "failure sending mail."

```
$EmailFrom = "emailaddress@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "otheremailaddress@gmail.com" 
$Subject = "Log file from server" 
$Subject = "Subject" 
$Body = "Here is the log file from the server" 
$File = "C:\Folder\LogFile.txt" 

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($File,'text/plain')

$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
$mailmessage.from = ($EmailFrom) 
$mailmessage.To.add($emailto) 
$mailmessage.Subject = $Subject 
$mailmessage.Body = $Body 

$mailmessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$username = "emailaddress@gmail.com" 
$pass = Get-Content "C:\Folder\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $pass);

$SMTPClient.Send($mailmessage)
```

I haven't received any email which I given own credential and from and to but getting exception calling message. Any reason?

Comment: From and to and user name and password and path everything given as per our req

Comment: Is there _anything else_ in the error message? Copy-paste it into the question body. While you are at it [edit] the question and format the code properly. Use the code block and add line breaks too.

Comment: Check out the answer I have written here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77041889/4742987

Comment: applied given code but it is not working

Comment: still same issues. calling  send with 1 argument; Failure sending mail

Comment: Sorry I did not realize you were connecting against gmail. Your username might not be in the correct format. Check out this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250309/4742987

Comment: Did you check error code/inner exception as per: *If you receive an SmtpException exception, check the StatusCode property to find the reason the operation failed. The SmtpException can also contain an inner exception that indicates the reason the operation failed.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send

Comment: This question needs more debugging details.